# While displaying a jsp page in spring boot, it displays along with jsp header file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

While displaying a jsp page in spring boot, it displays along with jsp header file....

JSP PAGE

```
<html>
<%@ include page language="java" contentType="text/jsp; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ include taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
   Hello World 
</body>
</html>
```

BROWSER OUTPUT

```
<%@ include page language="java" contentType="text/jsp; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%><%@ include taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>Hello World
```

Please Help.....

Answer (score 1):

please add below dependency in pom.xml to solve that issue. This dependency is use full for compiling JSP pages at runtime.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I already added this dependency....

Comment: please change contentType "text/jsp to text/html and try once.

Comment: nothing happened.....